# cell.clearValidation() is not working in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, angular, tabulator

I am using Tabulator latest version (4.7) in my angular application. Now I am adding one row on top and want to ignore validations for that row as it will not save data. So I was trying to call `cell.clearValidation()` from `validationFailed` function but it is not working. I am getting an error in console like -

```
tabulator.js:6672 Uncaught TypeError: self.table.modExists is not a function
    at CellComponent.clearValidation (tabulator.js:6672)
    at eval (eval at validationFailed (main.js:1), <anonymous>:1:6)
    at TabulatorTableComponent.validationFailed (tabulator-table.component.ts:551)
    at Tabulator.validationFailed (tabulator-table.component.ts:531)
    at success (tabulator.js:14091)
    at HTMLInputElement.onChange (tabulator.js:14345)
```

Have tried to call this on `cellClick` also but not worked..

Don't know how to use `cell.clearValidation()` , from which events we can call this function, etc. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in v4.7, this has been fixed for the 4.8 release that will be coming out early September 2020

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue.. Actually, `clearValidation` will work only with some `ValidationMode` on the Tabulator

see this link for more info..
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/validate#highlight